# PHP read json file key value

Tags: php, json

Trying to read a json file and assign values to php variables.

My json file looks like this:

```
{
"123456": {
    "fuelpump": {
        "name": "Pump XX",
        "address": "Address here",
        "8493024" <-- I WANT THIS THE VALUE 8493024: {
            "connectors": {
                "8493024-1": {
                    "infohere": "more info here"
                }
            }
        }
    }
},
"456789": {
    "fuelpump": {
        "name": "Pump YY",
        "address": "Address here",
        "8374769" <-- I WANT THIS THE VALUE 8374769: {
            "connectors": {
                "8374769-1": {
                    "infohere": "more info here"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

This is how my php code is looking:

```
<?php

$jsonfile = file_get_contents('jsonfile.json');

$jsonitems = json_decode($jsonfile);

foreach ($jsonitems as $location) {
    $name = $location->fuelpump->name; //This works OK
    $address = $location->fuelpump->address; // This ALSO OK
    $fuelPumpno = $location->fuelpump[2]; //This doesnt work. Here i want the key names 8493024 and 8374769
}
```

How can i get the name of the keys "8493024" and "8374769"?

Comment: The problem is that it's not an array, it's an object. Convert it to an array and you'll have better luck. Be aware though, the order of the attributes are not guaranteed for objects.

Comment: That is quite the badly-structured object. You'll need to get all of the keys from the `fuelpump` object, and then either filter out all the keys that you don't want, or find a way to match the one that you do.

Comment: See: `array_keys(get_object_vars($location->fuelpump))` and, to reiterate Christoffer's advice, _**do not**_ rely on the ordering of the keys, as it is neither constant nor predictable.

Comment: But honestly, for the sake of your sanity and that of anyone else that will ever have to interact with this data, I would strongly suggest asking the data provider to fix the format sooner rather than later. Eg: `{ "8493024": { ... } }` -> `{ "part_number": "8493024", "info"; { ... } }`

Answer (score 0):

You have to loop over the `fuelpump` properties to find the value.
If that is the structure of the json object, and it does not change, you can do with this:

```
foreach ($location->fuelpump as $key => $value) {
    if ($key !== 'name' && $key !== 'address') {
        $fuelPumpno = $key;
    }
}
```

**Another way**
it filters the keys of the `$location` object and get the first element of the result:

```
$fuelPumpno = current(array_filter(array_keys(get_object_vars($location->fuelpump)), function($el) {
   return $el !== 'name' && $el !== 'address';
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to filter only numeric values:

```
$jsonfile  = file_get_contents('jsonfile.json');
$jsonitems = json_decode($jsonfile, true);

$pumpNo = [];
foreach ($jsonitems as $data) {
    $pumpNo = array_merge($pumpNo, array_filter(array_keys($data["fuelpump"]), 'is_numeric'));
}

print_r($pumpNo);
```

It returns

```
Array
(
    [0] => 8493024
    [1] => 8374769
)
```